# Android firebase start a service when a specific type of message is received

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to start a background service when I received a special type of message. For this I am doing the following

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if(remoteMessage.getData().get("message").equals("something"){
              //start service
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, it only works when app is foreground , but when the app is in background `onMessageReceived` doesn't trigger.  Rather than it just show a notification .

What I want is to disable notification when app is in background , rather start a service.

I have looked other answers is SO, some of them suggest to accomplish this I need to send `data-message` . And I am sending data message from firebase console, but it is not working.

Comment: in your data message add one extra key-value pair so you can check that key in onMessageReceived()

Comment: Just print message received and see if it is "data" or "notification". As far as I remember, if you send message from Firebase console, it will go as notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is suggested is to send a `data`-*only* message payload. This is not possible using the Firebase Notifications Console.

When using the console, the message sent is treated as a `notification` message payload, and only adding *Custom Data* will the `data` payload be included. However, in that case, it still has both `notification` and `data` messages.

To send a `data`-*only* message payload, you'd need to build the request yourself through your own App Server or by [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817)