# Firebase Cloud Messaging send click_action

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Someone know one way to send the click_action from the firebase console ?

I just want to send the click_action button to use the notification even if the app is closed or in background.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to set the `click_action` parameter when using the Firebase Notifications console to send the message.

You'll have to build the payload on your own App Server, or use Postman ([instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143)) or cURL (instructions below) when testing.

---

---

**Sending Downstream Messages via cURL**

You can test sending messages using the FCM REST API by sending a request through cURL.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=<API_KEY>" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

<sub>Syntax retrieved from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#checkAPIkey).</sub>

The `API_KEY` indicated above is referring to the Server Key that can be seen in your [Firebase Console's Cloud Messaging Tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging).

The part where:

```
"{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

is, can be replaced with your own payload. See the [FCM HTTP Protocol Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) for more details.